# Oracle database version

Tags: oracle

How can I find out the version number of a database instance?

Note that I'm refering to the database instance rather than the Oracle software installation version.

Answer (score 7):

Simply run the following command from sqlplus command prompt:

```
select * from v$version;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;
```

Info shown like this

```
PRODUCT                                  VERSION     STATUS
---------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
NLSRTL                                   10.2.0.1.0  Production
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition   10.2.0.1.0  Prod
PL/SQL                                   10.2.0.1.0  Production
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `SYSTEM` or `DBA` access you can get the version number all by itself like this:

```
SELECT version FROM v$instance;
```

The result will look something like this:

```
VERSION
-----------------
11.2.0.2.0
```