# how to know the edition of oracle 12c database?

Tags: database, oracle, standards, enterprise

i need to know the edition of my 12c database (standard/enterprise)

i tried

```
Select * from v$version
```

and this i what i got:

```
Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.1.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
```

does this mean it's a standard? 
or i have to run some other query to know ?

Comment: See this question, 2nd answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984869/oracle-database-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that means that you have Standart.

SQL> select * from v$versioN;

### BANNER

Oracle Database 11g **Enterprise** Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production